# Checking or unchecking a kendo-checkbox placed on a kendo-grid row does not work

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I' am trying to add a checkbox column in a kendo-grid through Telerik's documentation. When I try to check or uncheck a checkbox from a row it does not work.

Here is my html:

```
<kendo-grid
    [data]="gridView"
    [selectable]="selectableSettings"
    [height]="317"
    [kendoGridSelectBy]="getWholeItemRow"
    [selectedKeys]="mySelection"
    (selectedKeysChange)="onSelectedKeysChange($event)"
    (remove)="confirmDeleteItemFromGrid($event)">
      <ng-template
      kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
        <button
        [disabled]='mySelection.length === 0'
        mat-flat-button
        class="btn-danger btn-sm"
        (click)="removeSelectedItems()">Remove selected items</button>
      </ng-template>
      <kendo-grid-checkbox-column width="15" showSelectAll="true" [columnMenu]="false" >
          <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate>
              <input class="k-checkbox" id="selectAllCheckboxId" kendoGridSelectAllCheckbox
                  [state]="selectAllState"
                  (selectAllChange)="onSelectAllChange($event)">
              <label class="k-checkbox-label"
               for="selectAllCheckboxId"></label>
          </ng-template>
      </kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
    ...
</kendo-grid>
```

TS:

```
export class ImagesGridComponent implements OnInit{

  @Input() captures: Array<Image>;
  @Input() positionSection: number;
  selectedImages: any[] = [];
  public selectAllState: SelectAllCheckboxState = 'unchecked';
  public mySelection: any[] = [];
  public gridView: GridDataResult;

  public selectableSettings: SelectableSettings = {
    enabled: false,
    checkboxOnly: false,
    mode: 'multiple'
  };

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadItems();
  }
```

Function that returns the object stored in the row. Used for [kendoGridSelectBy]:

```
  getWholeItemRow(context: RowArgs) {
    return context.dataItem;
  }
```

Function that should fired when the [selectedKeys] collection is updated: (NOT WORKING)

```
public onSelectedKeysChange(e) {
  const len = this.mySelection.length;

  if (len === 0) {
      this.selectAllState = 'unchecked';
  } else if (len > 0 && len < this.captures.length) {
      this.selectAllState = 'indeterminate';
  } else {
      this.selectAllState = 'checked';
  }
}
```

Function used when the header checkbox is checked/unchecked:

```
public onSelectAllChange(checkedState: SelectAllCheckboxState) {
  if (checkedState === 'checked') {
      this.mySelection = this.captures;
      this.selectAllState = 'checked';
  } else {
      this.mySelection = [];
      this.selectAllState = 'unchecked';
  }
}
```

Used to fill the grid:

```
  loadItems() {
    this.gridView = {
      data: this.captures,
      total: this.captures.length
    };
  }
}
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I edited the selectableSettings object and now works:

```
public selectableSettings: SelectableSettings = {
    enabled: true,
    checkboxOnly: true,
    mode: 'multiple'
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below properties in your kendo grid element :

**HTML :**

```
<kendo-grid [selectable]="selectableSettings" [kendoGridSelectBy]="onSelectedKey" [selectedKeys]="selectedData">
        <kendo-grid-checkbox-column showSelectAll="true" [columnMenu]="false">
        </kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

**TS :**

```
public setSelectableSettings(): void {
  this.selectableSettings = {
    checkboxOnly: false,
    mode: 'multiple',
  };
}

// This method is used to get the checked record data 
public onSelectedKey(context: RowArgs): any {
  return context.dataItem;
}
```

Kendo API reference :

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/CheckboxColumnComponent/

Comment: Thank you.. I was approaching to that idea but still not working.  I will add my .ts for more information.

Comment: Sure. I added the Kendo Grid checkbox column API reference link. Please have a look

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have provided the checkbox with the wrong class. Instead of `k-checkbox` you are using `k-radio`. Change it as shown below,

```
<input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="selectAllCheckboxId"
    kendoGridSelectAllCheckbox [state]="selectAllState"
    (selectAllChange)="onSelectAllChange($event)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's needed to be an input html tag.
For me work.